# i got some value error in my own function

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

In this function, the factor k returns the value in Dictionary a, and then saves the value in the list, and then returns the list by Fit_transforming the fid_t as scaler, but there is an error. What's the problem?

```py
def determineRank2(t, target, bid_t, k):
    encode = LabelEncoder()
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    # x = np.concatenate((t,n,bid_t,w,h,k),axis = 1).reshape(1,6,1)
    t = categorize_time(t)
    bid_t = scaler.fit_transform(bid_t)
    a = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3, 'e':4, 'f':5, 'g':6, 'h':7, 'i':8,
     'j':9, 'k':10, 'l':11, 'm':12, 'n':13, 'o':14, 'p':15, 'q':16, 'r':17,'w':18,
     'x':19, 'y':20, 'z':21, 'ab':22, 'cd':23, 'ef':24, 'gh':25, 'qw':26, 'er':27,
     'dz':28, 'df':29}
    new_list = []
    new_list = [t,target,bid_t,k]
    new_list = np.array(new_list)
    new_list = new_list.reshape(1, 1, 4)
    rank = model.predict(new_list)
    rank = round(rank.item(0))
    return rank
```

when i input some value like this

```
determineRank2("21:30:04", 3620,2 , "a")
```

the error show like this

```
<ipython-input-76-cea3690890e8> in determineRank2(t, target, bid_t, k)
 11     # x = np.concatenate((t,n,bid_t,w,h,k),axis = 1).reshape(1,6,1)
 12     t = categorize_time(t)
---> 13     bid_t = scaler.fit_transform(bid_t)


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
551         if y is None:
552             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 553             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
554         else:
555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit(self, X, y)
323         # Reset internal state before fitting
324         self._reset()
--> 325         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
326 
327     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
351         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy,
352                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 353                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
354 
355         data_min = np.nanmin(X, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
512                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
513                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 514                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
515             # If input is 1D raise error
516             if array.ndim == 1:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=2.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 
single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the error message, you should reshape your `bid_t` value.

From the [scaler documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit_transform) of `sklearn`:

> Parameters: X: numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]

Here your `bid_t` is not even an array.
So you have to make it look like an array:

```py
determineRank2("21:30:04", 3620, np.array([[2]]) , "a")
```

Comment: thank you for your comment.
Actually, I have to adjust the value to a value between 0 and 1.
Because the bad_t value of this model consists of a value between 0 and 1.
Do you happen to know how to solve this?

Comment: @Ailla What do you mean by "adjust"? If you want to clip, then min(max(bid_t, 0), 1) is enough, no need of min max scaler.